# 'Keyerror' while updating mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I'm a beginner at python and mongodb. I'm pushing the data from a multiple csv files to mongodb database where the new data should replace the existing data in the mongodb.I think it'll be helpful, while seeing the program,
my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import csv
path = 'C://test//xxx.csv'   

csvfile = open(path, "r")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile )
mongo_client=MongoClient() 
db=mongo_client.production
header= ["Instrument Name", "Date", "High", "Low", "Open", "Close", "Prev Close", "Volume"]
for each in reader:
    row={}
    k={}
    for field in header:
        if field=="Instrument Name":
            row[field]=each[field]
            k[field]=row[field]
            print k[field]
        elif field=="Date":
            row[field]=datetime.datetime.strptime(each[field], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )                    
        else:
            row[field]=float(each[field])
                    #row[field]=each[field]
    print row
    db.test.find_and_modify(query={'Instrument Name':k[field]},sort=1,update={row})
csvfile.close()
```

the output :

```
BANKNIFTY15MARFUT
{'Volume': 200.0, 'Prev Close': 18919.8, 'Instrument Name': 'BANKNIFTY15MARFUT', 'High': 19350.2, 'Low': 19350.2, 'Date': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 9, 15), 'Close': 19350.2, 'Open': 19350.2}
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0f0bc16df1c5> in <module>()
    263             print row
    264                 #row[field]=each[field]
--> 265             db.test.find_and_modify(query={"Instrument Name":k[field]},sort=1,update={row})
    266         csvfile.close()
    267 

KeyError: 'Volume'
```

Even though 'Volume' is present in my csv it throws Keyerror for Volume.Assist me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

After iteration, `field` is what was iterated last, I think you want it to be `"Instrument Name"`, so change:

```
db.test.find_and_modify(query={'Instrument Name':k[field]},sort=1,update={row})
```

To:

```
db.test.find_and_modify(query={'Instrument Name':k["Instrument Name"]},sort=1,update={row})
```

Or even better, since `k` only has `"Instrument Name"`:

```
db.test.find_and_modify(query=k,sort=1,update={row})
```

Also, `row` is already a dictionary, which is probably what `update` expects, so replace:

```
db.test.find_and_modify(query={"Instrument Name":k[field]},sort=1,update={row})
```

To:

```
db.test.find_and_modify(query=k,sort=1,update=row)
```